# Width of the Plateauxs in the IQHE

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

As the title said, Im studying the IQHE and I would like to know if there is some theory or idea to understand the widths of the Plateauxs that can be seen experimentally.

[image: IQHE]

As you can see in this experiment in GaAs/AlGaAs the widths of the plateaux seem to be bigger as we increase the magnetic field in the sample. Because the plateaux appear when the Fermi level is in between 2 Landau levels, and the separation between them is proportional to the magnetic field aplied then its easy to conclude that the plateaux should be larger as we increase the magnetic field because the separation between Landau levels is larger. However if we look at the v=5. This plateaux is smaller than their neighbours v=4 and v=6, so I dont know if the hypothesis that the width depends on the magnetic field is true or there is something else.

Comment: My guess would be that the theory deals with a perfect 2DEG, and the experiments deal with imperfect materials. The quantization does not suffer from this discrepancy, but the concrete level transitions might.

Comment: In principle one of the "things" about IQHE is that disorder is the reason why this plateauxs exist. Disorder broadens the Landau levels, giving this quantization in the xy resistivity for a range of B. I dont know if disorder affects every Landau level equally, meaning that the broadening is equally or affects more certein levels.